# Map multiple urls to the same action in ASP.NET WebAPI 2 using routing attributes

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have an action method in a controller thus:-

```
[RoutePrefix("api/forces")]
public class ForceController : Controller
{
   [HttpGet]
   [Route("{showAll?}")]
   public IHttpActionResult GetForces(bool? showAll)
   {
       IEnumerable<Force> forces=  forceRepository.GetAll().ToList();
       if(!showAll)
        {
            forces = forces.ToList().Where(u => u.IsActive);
        }
       return Ok(new { data= forces, message = "The forces are with you" });
   }
}
```

I will like both urls below to be routed to the action

```
api/forces
api/forces/true
```

I thought the current route attribute will work, but it only works for the second url i.e. api/forces/true and not the first. api/users.

Comment: Try `GetForces(bool? showAll = null)` or `GetForces(bool? showAll = false)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [Attribute Routing in ASP.NET Web API 2: Optional URI Parameters and Default Values](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#optional)

> You can make a URI parameter optional by adding a question mark to the
>   route parameter. If a route parameter is optional, you must define a
>   default value for the method parameter.

```
[RoutePrefix("api/forces")]
public class ForceController : Controller {
   [HttpGet]
   [Route("{showAll:bool?}")]
   public IHttpActionResult GetForces(bool? showAll = true) {...}
}
```

> In this example, `/api/forces` and `/api/forces/true` return the same resource.

Alternatively, you can specify a default value inside the route template, as follows:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/forces")]
public class ForceController : Controller {
   [HttpGet]
   [Route("{showAll:bool=true}")]
   public IHttpActionResult GetForces(bool? showAll) {...}
}
```

Comment: In your  #2 sample maybe you don't need a nullable bool anymore, am I mistaken? ;P

Comment: Thanks, I went for the first one. It works like the blood of Jesus.

Answer (score 3):

You could just use the default route `[Route()]` which would force the `showAll` parameter to be passed via querystring. That would accept

```
/api/forces
/api/forces?showAll=true
/api/forces?showAll=false
```

Comment: This is the way to go, since the other approaches aren't RESTful at all.

Answer (score 1):

You need to supply a value to the `showAll` parameter because it is not optional (being nullable doesn't count). Making it optional should fix the problem.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("{showAll?}")]
public IHttpActionResult GetForces(bool? showAll = null)
{
    ...
}
```